# Drop all obs of group if condition is met

Tags: panel, subset, stata

suppose I have the following panel data (didn't include time var for simplicity)

```
clear

input   id  var

        1   .      
        1   0      
        1   0      
        1   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        3   1    
        3   .     
        3   .
        3   0
end
```

I would like to delete all groups that have all missing data in their group, that is, I want my data to be like:

```
        id  var

        1   .      
        1   0      
        1   0      
        1   .      
        3   1    
        3   .     
        3   .
        3   0
```

I tried doing a `gen todrop = var[_N]`, but for some reason, for some groups it doesn't work. Any thoughts? I thought about `sort`ing `id var`, then doing a cascade replace, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can verify whether all observations hold the same value by checking first and last observations in each panel, after appropriate `sort`ing. The same principle applies here. I'll use the `missing()` function:

```
clear
set more off

input   id  myvar
        1   .      
        1   0      
        1   0      
        1   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        2   .     
        3   1    
        3   .     
        3   .
        3   0
end

bysort id (myvar) : gen todrop = missing(myvar[1]) & missing(myvar[_N])

list, sepby(id)
```

In this case, just checking the first one also works. If it's missing, all others are.

See `help by`.

Comment: Note that because this code uses `missing()` it will work for any numeric variable regardless of the missing value coding, and because it also checks `myvar[_N]`, it will work for string variables as well as numeric variables. Elegant.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski makes good points. Future readers note that string variables sort the other way around compared to numeric variables: in ascending order, string missing values (`""`) come first.

Answer (score 0):

Roberto has provided a solution which is however case specific and might lead to wrong outcome.
In fact, suppose you have an observation as follows:

```
id myvar
2 .
2 1
2 .
```

Using Roberto's code, you would remove this group, while in the question you need to remove only if **all** observations are missing.

Therefore I suggest you use a different approach, as follows:

```
levels id, local(groups) // creates unique values for id (no need to egen if you don't really have to)

foreach iter of local groups {

    mdesc myvar if id == "`iter'" // use mdesc and put double quotes if id is a string
    drop if id == "`iter'" &  r(percent) == 100  // r(percent) is stored after mdesc


}
```

Comment: To be honest, I should comment that Mino's comment is not correct and his solution is a little bit long while tending to be slow for large data set. Roberto's code is working properly along with the sort of *myvar* (within a parentheses) by *bysort* command).

Answer (score 0):

Roberto's code definitely works. Also does below code. The only contribution is that the original order (sort) of observations is kept if you might want it.

```
egen todrop2 = min(missing(myvar)), by(id)
```